# Memory leak in apache-tomcat-8.0.14

Tags: java, tomcat, grails

Running a standard tomcat 8.0.14, fresh install out of the box, running it at a hosting company. 
I am using java jre1.8.0_05 on a CentOS server. Only changes from the start was to change some ports.

All good so far, get a nice welcome to Apache message, then my hosting company kills it because it has gone past 1048 mb. So thought I would set the max memory in setenv.sh

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -server -Xms48m -Xmx256m"
```

Which should set the max memory to 256, but it just continues growing if I deploy hello.war (basically, ran grails hello world then added a single render this is a rest to the project). Its now up to 399 mb

So is there any way to set a hard limit, and why would a hello world feel that it needs 399mb

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Was there any OOM error? If so pls provide that details.
What JDK you are using? Did you monitor heap usage to find out if it's issue with Eden or tenured space.
I would suggest to do a memory sampling using tool such as jvisualvm to find out which class is using that much memory.

Definitely something is eating your memory and you can not find until you do a sampling.

Alternatively you can also take heap dump to find out which object is growing.

Comment: The JDK is jdk1.8.0_11, did not monitor heap

Comment: OOM is an acronym for "Out of memory", i.e. OutOfMemoryError. Very Google-able

Answer (score 1):

Have you used Grails before :) ? It's great, but it uses more memory than an equivalent Java-based app. This is from a few different sources, one being that every class has a `MetaClass`. A small price to pay for everything Groovy provides.

This not a serious problem in general because the extra memory used isn't too bad. Note though that what you're seeing has nothing to do with Grails or Tomcat - you can easily use (or appear to use) more memory than the max specified. This blog post is a few years old, but still very relevant: https://blogs.oracle.com/jrockit/entry/why_is_my_jvm_process_larger_t

One other interesting feature of newer JDKs that's somewhat related to this is that now that the JRockit JVM has been merged into the 'main' JVM, there is no 'permanent' generation, and hence no more permgen issues. Strings and classes make up the bulk of the content in the permanent generation, so it's more apparent in Grails because of the large number of files (many created at runtime). The only thing that really changed is what would be in permgen will be somewhere else, but the same memory usage is incurred, so a true permgen leak will be a general leak and will crash the server. Again, this is related but not what you're seeing.

One other thing that's odd is that Java 1.8 doesn't really work with Grails - I'm surprised you're getting as far as you are. Different minor versions have different problems, but I wasn't able to get a combination of settings that actually worked. You should drop down to 1.7 until support for Java 8 is officially announced for both Grails and Groovy.

Comment: I'll try yo go down to java 1.7 and see if that makes things happier :)